# Gather testcases with TestSuite across packages

Tags: java, testing, junit

When we have many **JUnit4 test cases scattered** in many packages, is it *"good"* to put them together in one TestSuite? like this:

```
package my.package.tests;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    my.package.a.testMyService.class,
    my.package.b.testMyBackend.class,
    ...
})

public class AllTests {}
```

Or, can we rely on it as a way to manage our test cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I don't use test suites, except in very specific cases. I much prefer to use a runner which finds the test cases by reflection, such as the ant junit task or maven surefire/failsafe. This way I won't forget to add a test to a suite and then discover 2 weeks later that it has been failing, or someone 'temporarily ' removes a test case with the same result.

I use test suites for cases where I need fine grained control over the order or I need to run the same tests again and again.

Comment: It's good to keep it simple.  The reason I want to control test cases in small grain is it's needed sometime.  For example, one test case connect to an remote DB, which itself is unstable and under testing.  As other example as one test case will be 10 minute long run.